# update the microsoft power bi report automatically when updating the databse

Tags: sql-server, angular, powerbi-desktop

I'm generating some simple BI reports for a dashboard of KPIs in an angular App. Well my question is can power BI update the data of the report automatically whenever i update the database? .For the DB i'm using sql server .

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for

[Real-time streaming in Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-real-time-streaming)

There is one more way you can do that [Data refresh in Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/refreshdataset)

I would put my 2 cents on Data refresh

Answer (score 1):

You can use a python script to automate this, I have used this project before and it works https://github.com/dubravcik/pbixrefresher-python

You will need to convert the .py file into an .exe file and run it on a task scheduler and set your preferred execution rate.